# Is my SQL syntax really wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

This is the code I use to insert the values `$id`, `$str` and `$name` in a database:

```
$r=mysql_query("INSERT INTO varta(id,data,name) VALUES('$id','$str','$name');");
```

But I get a syntax error for the above statement. Why is that? Is my syntax really wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Impossible to know without the values of the variables.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Please, every time you have a question, if you get an error, _say what that error is_. Thanks! (Downvoted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding white spaces between your query words and make sure you **escape the input**:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$r=mysql_query("INSERT INTO varta (id,data,name) VALUES ('$id','$str','$name');");
```

Or better yet - take a look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK on face value, so long as your input variables are correctly escaped. Try this, so you can see the statement you're executing:

```
$s = "INSERT INTO varta (id,data,name) VALUES('$id','$str','$name');";
echo $s;
$r = mysql_query($s);
```

Check that your variables don't contain an apostrophe, such as "Daisy O'Donnel" (this would be a sign that you've not escaped them correctly).

Comment: OK, you write up the whole how its open to abuse thing, I was trying to point them how to see the error..

Comment: BugFinder, once an omission is pointed out, it's okay to fix retrospectively! I've done that now, and +1 for separating the query out so it can be echoed.